# SQL command will not execute in ASP web app

Tags: javascript, oracle, http, asp-classic

I'm making a web app using ASP-classic, and I'm trying to update some values in an Oracle database.  Here is what I have so far.

```
<script>
function getUpdateHTML()
{
    var lockoutcheck;
    if (document.getElementById("cellRollLockoutYN").checked)
    {
        lockoutcheck = "'Y'";
    }
    else
    {
        lockoutcheck = "'N'";
    }
    var updatestring = "RollInventoryViewDev.asp?updatelockout=";
    updatestring = updatestring + lockoutcheck + "&updatepatterndepth=";
    updatestring = updatestring + document.getElementById("cellProductPatternDepthAvg").value + "&";
    updatestring = updatestring + "action=update&sort=roll_id&sortdir=<%=intSortDir%>&id=<%=intRollID%>&iddt=<%=StrRollIdDt%>&seqnum=<%=intRollSeqNum%>&findesc=<%=strRollFinishDescription%>&fincd=<%=strRollFinishCD%>&diam=<%=dblRollDiameter%>&crown=<%=dblRollCrown%>&crownaim=<%=dblRollCrownAim%>&prosrough=<%=intRollProsRoughness%>&peaksrough=<%=intRollPeaksRoughness%>&hardness=<%=intRollHardness%>&metalcd=<%=strRollMetalCD%>&rolltype=<%=strRollType%>&lockout=<%=chrRollLockoutYN%>&depthavg=<%=dblProductPatternDepthAvg%>";
    <!--alert("Attempting to Update Record with Lockout: " + lockoutcheck + " and Pattern Depth: " + document.getElementById("cellProductPatternDepthAvg").value);-->
    window.open(updatestring,"_self")
}
</script>





<% 
'If update selected, then update information
If Request.QueryString("action") = "update" Then

    sqlQry = "update tp07_roll_inventory_row set roll_lockout_yn = "&chrUpdateLockout&", product_pattern_depth_avg = "&dblUpdateDepthAvg&" where roll_id = "&intRollID&""%>
    <script>alert("<%=sqlQry%>");</script>

    <%

    ' Turn error handling on.  If an error is generated, our program will continue to execute and 
    '  the error code will be stored in Err.number.
    'On Error Resume Next

    ' Execute SQL code
    Set RS = dbConn.Execute(sqlQry, RowsAffected)
    ' If an error occured then construct an error message to display to the user
    If err<>0 then
        message="Unable to Perform Update: "
        for each objErr in dbConn.Errors
            message = message & objErr.Description & "<br>"

        next
        ' Set message color to red to indicate failure
        messageColor = "#DD2222"
    ' If there was no error then generate a "success" message to display to the user
    Else
        message="Update Successful: " & rowsAffected & " row(s) updated."
        ' Set message color to green to indicate success
        messageColor = "#22DD22"
    End If
    Response.write(message)


End If
%>
```

It generates an sql query which will look like `update tp07_roll_inventory_row set roll_lockout_yn = 'N', product_pattern_depth_avg = 2.6 where roll_id = 8502;`

It then alerts with the SQL Query (just so I know it's formatted correctly), turns on error handling and then executes.

If it fails to update, it should print "Unable to Perform Update: " and all of the error codes.

Right now, it prints "Unable to Perform Update: " but none of the error codes print.  And it's definitely failing to update.

EDIT:  I added my javascript that generated the new URL after update is clicked, so maybe there's a problem in here.

Originally, this script was down below, but now that I've moved it above and commented out On Error,  There's a `Object required: ''` error on the `Set RS = dbConn.Execute(sqlQry, RowsAffected)` line

EDIT:  Here's the subroutine that opens that database connection and the code that opens the connection and queries the database for data to fill the tables

```
%>
<%Sub dbConnect()
    Set dbConn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    dbConn.Open "Provider=MSDAORA.1;Password=database;User ID=dba_prd;Data Source=devtm2tcp"
End Sub

Sub dbDisconnect()
    dbConn.Close
    Set dbConn = Nothing
End Sub
%>




<% ' 
    boolDetailTable = false
    Call dbConnect()
    sqlQry = "SELECT * FROM TP07_ROLL_INVENTORY_ROW"
    if Len(strSort) > 0 then
        sqlQry = sqlQry + " ORDER BY " & strSort
        if intSortDir <> "1" then
            sqlQry = sqlQry + " DESC"
        end if
    end if

    getRS sqlQry
%>
```

[image]

Comment: What database driver are you using? Does it produces an Errors collection?

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: remove `On Error Resume Next` for the time being and see if you get any errors.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ:  I did that, and now I get an HTTP 500 error

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn how would I fix that?

Comment: @Jeff I'm using the ADO Recordset object.  It does have an Errors object, as seen in the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to this and see if see any errors printed: I have added `err.description` to the message.

```
<%

    ' Turn error handling on.  If an error is generated, our program will continue to execute and 
    '  the error code will be stored in Err.number.
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Execute SQL code
    Call dbConnect()
    Set result = dbConn.Execute(sqlQry, rowsAffected)
    ' If an error occured then construct an error message to display to the user
    If err.Number <> 0 then
        message="Unable to Perform Update: "
    'get the error description from err object
        message = message & Err.Description & "<br>"

    'get errors, if any, from connection object
        for each objErr in dbConn.Errors
            message = message & objErr.Description & "<br>"
        next
        ' Set message color to red to indicate failure
        messageColor = "#DD2222"
    ' If there was no error then generate a "success" message to display to the user
    Else
        message="Update Succssfull: " & rowsAffected & " row(s) updated."
        ' Set message color to green to indicate success
        messageColor = "#22DD22"
    End If
    Call dbDisconnect()
            Response.Write(message)
End If
%>
```

Comment: Unable to Perform Update: Object Required

Comment: what is dbconn ? if that is a connection string, you have to first opne a connection object using that

Comment: I think it might be because dbConn didn't exist yet.  I just realized that my database connection code wasn't happening until after the update code (for some stupid reason).  I moved the connection code above the update code, and now it just hangs whenever I click update.

Comment: dbConn is the connection object.  I just tried moving the update code to the bottom of the program (so it wouldn't execute until after all of the HTML is executed), and now I'm getting Object Required again

Comment: can you show where you open the dbconn ? you can edit your post. Maybe you should edit your post and show the page as you have it now.

Comment: it does not matter if you put the asp code before the html, the server side code is executed first anyway. Only thing is you have to create a connection object and open it before you do the `execute`

Comment: Sure, I updated the OP with the dbConnect() subroutine and the code that calls dbConnect.  I'll also add a screenshot of the app

Comment: I GOT IT!  I just added a dbConnect() to the update subroutine to make sure that the connection is still there.  Thank you so much! I'll accept your answer